# Setting Widget Focus in Gtkada

Tags: gtk, ada

I'm trying to create a simple test program in Gtkada to bring up a Dialog box upon leaving a specific textbox. I have managed this part, but am having problems resetting the focus back to the original textbox when the Dialog's 'Ok' button is pressed. 
The general idea is that the user enters something into a textbox and when they click/tab out of the box (focus out event), some simple Alphanumeric validation is done. If the validation fails, the user is warned with a Dialog, and focus is returned to the textbox they entered erroneous data into.
All I am after is a simple example of how to set the focus back to a textbox when you close the Dialog box which clicking out of the textbox originally called. In Gtkada... I'm using version 2.2 of Gtkada. I can't change the version of Gtkada, or use a different program or language!
Much obliged!

Tim

Comment: Post simplest possible code showing this problem here...

Comment: Have since had a meeting and it has been decided that We're going to do the whole ream of validation checking on a button click. No focus shifting/setting required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant solution, GUI-wise, is to do the validation on a leave_event on each input field, and if that fails display an error message (in red or some such) next to the field. But do not display a dialog or force the focus to a specific field, that would interfere with what the user is trying to do (imagine: I enter an incorrect email address, press tab, get the dialog which I do not read (like most users), start typing my name for the next field, but since the focus went back to the email address, I have no overridden that one and lost my previous input).

If you still want to grab the focus, `Gtk.Widget.Grab_Focus` is the procedure you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd unfortunately come to most of those conclusions myself, but I'm quite limited to what I can produce by 30 years of form conventions. The guys that are going to be using this Simulator panel expect a certain correlation between what I produce and previous Sim panels. I believe we're now going for an 'all in one' 'Send' button click validity check and Dialog box with a message telling the user which fields are erroneous. No field focus changing will happen, so no screwing around with where the users expect the cursor to be. Thanks again